# Rails polymorphic_url with multiple parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can i make polymorphic_url with multiple parameters?
I want to add two parameters with my pagination partials (my index page has selection)

`params[:type] == 'normal'` ,`params[:country] == 'us'`

index.erb

```
<%=
  render template: "layouts/pagination",
  locals: {
    pagination_info: @pagination_info
    model: User
  } 
%>
```

pagination.erb

```
<% pagination_info.available_pages.each do |page| %>
  <%= link_to page, polymorphic_url(model, page: page) %>
<% end %>
```

`pagination_info` has available_pages information and next and previous page link informations.
`pagination_info.available_pages` looks like => [0, 1, 2, 3, ... ]

Can i add multiple parameters to polymorphic_url?

---

I changed my code like this and find out this works, but i thought it is not good for reuse-able code (i will use pagination in other pages, and my other pages have 0 params, 1 params, 3 params, ... etc )

index.erb

```
<%=
  render template: "layouts/pagination",
  locals: {
    pagination_info: @pagination_info
    model: User,
    type: params[:normal],
    country: params[:country]
  } 
%>
```

pagination.erb

```
<% pagination_info.available_pages.each do |page| %>
  <%= link_to page, polymorphic_url(model, page: page, type: type, country: country) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just define the partial to take an extra hash option:

```erb
<%=
  render template: "layouts/pagination",
  locals: {
    pagination_info: @pagination_info
    model: User,
    url_options: {
      type: params[:normal],
      country: params[:country]
    }
  } 
%>
```

```erb
<% pagination_info.available_pages.each do |page| %>
  <%= link_to(page, polymorphic_path(model, page: page, **url_options)) %>
<% end %>
```

`**` is the double splat operator and will convert a hash into keyword arguments. This works even with older methods that pass a hash as a postional argument.

```
def standin_for_polymorphic_path(record_or_hash_or_array, options = {})
  puts options.inspect
end

standin_for_polymorphic_path('bar', x: 1, **{ y: 2})
# outputs {:x=>1, :y=>2}
```

Also if your partial contains very little actual HTML and just method calls its almost better to define it as a helper method - that way you get a argument error if its called incorrectly and IRB/your editor can look up the method and its definition.

```erb
module PaginationHelper
  def pagination_link(page, **url_options)
    opts = url_options&.dup || {}
    opts.merge(page: page) # set whatever other options you want
    link_to(page, polymorphic_path(model, **opts))
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved my time. Can i use optional or default arguments on `polymorphic_path(**url_options)`?

The `**url_options.permit!` method allows pagination to work in the absence of params but it exposed controller and action name into url. In the situation of presence of params, error 'undefined method 'permit!' for {:type=>'normal', :country=>'us'}:Hash' occurs.

Comment: The use of  `polymorphic_path(**url_options = {})` worked without params, but failed to maintain params when clicking the link in the pagenation after searching (ex. `/users?page=1&type='normal'&country='us'`  has been changed as `/users?page=2`)

Even without params, it would be good if  `**url_options` could be used default argument (situation1, with argument. situation2, without argument), but it doesn't work well even if I try many things.
I'm sorry to bother you, but could you help me?

Comment: When i use `polymorphic_path(**url_options)` without params(without url options), an error `unable to convert unpermitted parameters to hash` occurs.

Comment: As I said earlier - it would be a lot easier if you just wrote a method instead of using a partial. In a partial you can use `local_assigns.fetch(:url_options, {})` if you want to provide a defualt value.

Comment: The reason you're getting a nomethod error is that you're calling `permit!` on a hash and not a ActionController::Parameters instance. Write a method and handle your inputs in a better way and you'll figure it out.

Comment: Your answer sloved my problem. Thanks a lot